# Why is a custom Array slower than the vanilla version?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I was curious about the speed of different ways of modifying JavaScript's built-in array class, so I made a little test:

http://jsperf.com/array-vs-custom-array

This compares three different ways of adding a remove function to Array. A remove() function added with Object.create() seems to be wildly (~90% in Chrome) slower than the same function with .call() or added to Array.prototype. They all do the same thing, and are in fact the same function, so I'm curious as to why there is a speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is function lookup time adds up.

In the first case you have already looked up `remove`'s address so it's a simple matter of calling the function.

The `Object.create()` method will have to first look in `Array.prototype` and then find it in the new object's properties.

The last prototype replacement method incurs a lookup time for the function in the prototype.

I'm not sure how to test this hypothesis, but I've seen something like this before when optimizing some python code.

Comment: Interesting.. I modified the test to include a mint example where I just set add remove on the array after creating it. That seems to be fastest and functionally identical to the chocolate Object.create() method but with the downside that .remove will be enumerable.. http://jsperf.com/array-vs-custom-array/3

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that a function call will first look at the immediate object and _then_ at the prototype. So shouldn't chocolate and vanilla be the same? Hrm..

Comment: In case you are still interested in this test, I think part of the problem is that you had too much in the timed section. If you move the push call into the test setup the performance for remove is similar for all three types.
http://jsperf.com/array-vs-custom-array/4